# Sequel/FactoryGirl trying to force a Timestamp(6) into a Timestamp(0) no matter what is listed in the factory

Tags: ruby, teradata, factory-bot, sequel

I'm trying to insert into a Teradata table that has a column like this:

```
 END_DT TIMESTAMP(0),
```

In my Factory for this table, I give that column the following value:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :'database/table' do
    ...
    end_dt '5555-12-31 00:00:00'
    ...
  end
end
```

However, when I try to insert into this table, the is the SQL statement that tries to run:

```
INSERT INTO DATABASE.TABLE(END_DT) VALUES ('5555-12-31 00:00:00.000000')
```

Note the extra 6 zeros on the end, which cause the statement to fail for an invalid timestamp.

I've tried using strftime, just using a Date, but nothing seems to work.

Sequel seems hell bent on adding those 6 extra zeros, and I can't figure out why.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to explicitly tell Sequel not to use fractional timestamps:

```
DB.extend_datasets{def supports_timestamp_usecs?; false end}
```

Hopefully that will work for you, but it may depend on your adapter.